# how to shorten the syntax of calling a function only if arguments aren't null in c#?

Tags: c#, function, null

let's say I have the following code:

```
var arg = getArg();
if(arg != null)
{
  foo(arg);
}
```

is there a way to shorten the null checking + function calling?
for example is there an operator like perhaps 'safe' that would work like

```
foo(safe arg);
```

that would translate to "call foo only if 'arg' isn't null" ?
I basically want not to send arguments that may be null to functions, but do so in a short way.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you acces to foo implementation code and have right to change it?

Comment: To answer your question, no, you cannot shorten it in the way you are asking. However, the function (or method, rather, since this is C#), if designed properly, should not care whether it was passed `null` as a parameter. For instance, your `foo` method should have something at the top along the lines of `if (arg == null) return;` if it should not be operating when it is passed a null value.

Comment: Let's say I don't want or can't change foo() so adding a null check inside foo is not desirable, but rather I want to avoid the function call all-together since I know it will be useless with a null argument.

Comment: The closest thing to what you are describing is that you can use the null-conditional operator `?` if you are calling `foo` _on_ `arg`. i.e. If you did `arg?.foo()`, then `foo` would only get called if `arg` is not null.

Comment: An alternative is that you can use a tertiary operator within the parameter section of the method to pass a default value if `arg` is null. e.g. `foo(arg == null ? new ArgObject() : arg);`

Comment: @Abion47 I see. Would you think that is a feature worthwhile having? I find entering the function (which I may not have written) and changing it rather tedious no?

Comment: This is a sign of a serious code smell.  There is something wrong with getArg(), it almost surely ought to throw an exception.  Well, not too late to fix it, throw the exception after calling it.  Fwiw, never try to paper-over a serious design problem, this should hurt and make anybody that reads it want to fix it.

Comment: @Abion47 ternary operator still needs the check for null and the question asked for removing the check. Also, your first suggestion completely ignores the design and semantics of  the class.

Comment: @Abion47: "the function (or method, rather, since this is C#), if designed properly, should not care whether it was passed `null` as a parameter" - disagree. Passing a non-`null` reference can very well be a prerequisite for the invocation to make sense. As a `void` method, it might check its argument and immediately return if the argument is `null`, but non-`void` methods cannot necessarily do that (because a "default value" does not necessarily make sense). Instead, an `ArgumentNullException` should be thrown in any case, at which point it is evidently the responsibility of calling code ...

Comment: ... to make sure it does not pass `null`.

Comment: @DesertFox: absent more context, I can't say code such as in the example is _wrong_ per se. But I do agree with Hans that there's a "smell". That is, a well-designed API does not typically return `null` values. I know that there are plenty of examples of methods that return `null` to indicate some status, but typically those should be exceptional cases, and dealt with by throwing an exception. It's why I believe that this type of scenario really shouldn't come up much in the first place. Yes, Hans is conjecturing; but we all have to, given the lack of context, and his note is reasonable.

Comment: @DesertFox: _"the question was about removing the need for null checks"_ -- when methods aren't allowed to return `null` as part of their normal operation, then you don't have to check a result for `null` before passing it to something else, thus _"removing the need for null checks"_. For example, one thing I really like about C# vs. C++ is that `new` _always_ returns non-`null` values; the only way it can't is if an exception is thrown.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper My comment about the method immediately returning on null was just an example (hence the "For instance"). My point is that the function should already be designed to receive a null value as a parameter and be able to behave accordingly. Whether that's returning or throwing an exception or something else entirely depends on the context, but its ability to properly execute shouldn't hinge on a check that the calling code has to make prior to the call.

Comment: @DesertFox The question merely asked for shortening the syntax of the null check, not necessarily for removing it entirely. And I was illustrating that if OP can't or won't change `getArgs` or `foo`, using a ternary in the parameter field is the closest one can get to removing a null check _entirely_.

Comment: @Abion47: If it throws an exception in case of a `null` argument, a prior check executed by the calling code *is* reasonable. The fact that an exception gets thrown means "do not call this method unless you have something non-`null` to pass". And the check by the calling code means "If I have an `arg`, I need to call the method on it, but if I have no `arg`, nothing should happen."

Comment: @HansPassant: "There is something wrong with getArg(), it almost surely ought to throw an exception." - how do you know the OP is not dealing with an optional argument that may or may not be there?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper In which case, again, see my second or third reply for ways to condense the check. I stand by my saying that, in many cases, a check may not even be necessary depending on how the method is coded, and for cases in which it is unavoidable, there is no syntactic sugar to eliminate it completely, and there are only a handful of ways that avoid having to type it all out.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: **NO, THERE IS NOT**

Suggestion:

Without complicated code or inclusion of third-party libraries to the mix, I think you have to consider the following points when designing your code:

- What is this code supposed to do for the range of arguments to be provided?
- Is whoever calling that piece of code aware of the possible results of said method?

First thing you could do is document the methods.

In your example, it seems that `getArg` can return `null`. So, a good approach could be:

```
/// <summary>
/// Describe your method here
/// </summary>
/// <returns>Describe what it returns</returns>
/// <remarks>May return NULL if (explain why)</remarks>
public TypeName getArg()
{
    //do your code here
}
```

Awesome. So, now, whoever intend to use the method `getArg()` will have a good description of what the method does and, hey, it can even give you a `null` instance in the return.

You can do the same with `foo()`. Now, is not clear if `foo()` is supposed to work or not if a `null` is passed in the parameter. But from your description of the functionality, it seems it will break the app if it is.

If that is the case, you probably want to make `foo()` throw an exception.

So, a good approach would be:

```
/// <summary>
/// Describe your method here
/// </summary>
/// <param name="args">Describe the argument here</param>
/// <exception cref="System.ArgumentNullException">When args is null</exception>
public void foo(TypeName args)
{
    if (args == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(args));
    //do your code here
}
```

We are almost there.

Now, the piece of code that ties all together...

You know from the documentation (you) provided that:

- `args` can be `null`
- `foo()` throws an exception if `args` is `null`

And, from documentation, you know you want to avoid `try catch` as much as you can due to performance.

- DRUM ROLL *

The code you provided should be the final code :)

```
var args = getArgs();
if (args != null)
    foo(args);
```

But again. This is just using standard .net code.

Either way, documenting your code is always desirable, giving context and preventing bugs from lack of knowledge of how to use the code :)

Comment: The expected answer would be to use a ternary operator, why didn't you include that in your answer?

Comment: not at all. The question was: "call foo only if 'arg' isn't null" ? I basically want not to send arguments that may be null to functions, but do so in a short way.

Comment: a ternary operator wouldn't remove the check for null.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think the "don't call if this value is `null`" ought to be an infrequent enough occurrence that typing out the `if` shouldn't be that big of a problem. That said …

If you're willing to set up some extension methods to handle various parameter list counts, you could do something like this:

```
static class Extensions
{
    public static void IfNotNull<T>(Action<T> func, T arg)
        where T : class
    {
        if (arg != null)
        {
            func(arg);
        }
    }
}
```

then you can do this:

```
var arg = getArg();

Extensions.IfNotNull(foo, arg);
```

Unfortunately, the compiler won't infer the delegate type to perform the above using the extension method syntax, which would shorten the syntax more. But you can use the `using static ...` feature to bring the `Extensions` method into scope so that you can call without the class name, like this:

```
IfNotNull(foo, arg);
```

Extend the idea to other function signatures as needed. You'll just mirror the patterns used for the `Action` and `Func` delegate types.

Note also that the above approach adds the overhead of a delegate instance allocation and invocation. It is not actually exactly the same as just putting in the `if` statement. In most cases, it won't have any impact on performance at all.

If you want to avoid the delegate overhead *and* you're willing to write a new method for *every* method you want to treat this way, you can of course add that intermediate method:

```
void SafeFoo(ArgType arg)
{
    if (arg != null)
    {
        foo(arg);
    }
}
```

That seems like a real pain to me, especially if you don't have a lot of places you want to avoid the `if`. But it's there.

Otherwise, no. The language offers a few different shortcuts for dealing with `null` values, but nothing built-in would do what you're asking for that specific scenario.